# getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE) inside FlutterFragmentActivity not working?

Tags: flutter, screenshot, disable

I try to disable screenshot in android with flutter. 
I try this :

```
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    //not working

    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure but try this...

try removing `getActivity()`

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

i hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get access to the activity (and then window) using from the `Registrar` via `registrarFor`

```dart
    Registrar registrar = registrarFor(null);
    Activity activity = registrar.activity();
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Feels super hacky, but it appears to work.